# Which CSS style sheet should I place my web font in?

Tags: css, stylesheet, webfonts

I normally place my fonts in my master style sheet so that they're only declared once. But I'm working on somebody else's site and they've declared it in individual style sheets for individual pages (although the web font is used across the whole site) is there any harm in doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

If the font rule is in place for every stylesheet included in its corresponding page then the behavior will be exactly the same as if it was just in a master stylesheet.

The only issue would be if you needed to change the font, as you would have to change it in all the individual stylesheets.

There would not be any performance implications as the first time the user visits the site, the font will be downloaded and cached and from then on, any other page will obtain it from the cache.

Comment: Yeah that would be a pain. 
Would there be any performance issues? Will the web font have to be downloaded multiple times if declared multiple times or will it get cached and only downloaded the once?

Comment: The font is downloaded once and cached.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "harm" in doing it this way, it will work.

For me though, it's a very inefficient way of coding... If declaring styles individually for each page is an absolute MUST, then why not give the wrapping elements / div's on each page unique ID's and target them from one stylesheet using their unique ID selector?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the font is used across all pages I would add it to master stylesheet instead of copying it to separate smaller sheets which are created for specific purpose in it's page, along with anything that is used across all the pages.

Organizing stylesheets (or any code) this way removes unnecessary duplications and allows global changes to be made faster and easier. It also increases readability.